# org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/ipc/CallerContext$Builder

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am trying to connect my hive jdbc client to hiveserver2.
 i am using following maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1000.2.4.2.12-1</version>
</dependency>

hiveserver2.start() started my hiveserver2.
```

but when i start my jdbc client with followin code :

```
val con: Connection = DriverManager
      .getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "")
    val stmt: Statement = con.createStatement
stmt.execute("create table if not exists student (id int))
```

it gives me following exception :

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/ipc/CallerContext$Builder   at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:256)  at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:242)  at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:254)

Can anybody either help me to identify the reason of this or solution please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to connect to hiveserver2 through beeline? something like 
`beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen due to multiple reason:-

1. Either the corresponding jar wont be available which is the
   hivejdbcdriver jar with the right version eg: "hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar"
   or sometimes you may to use
   "hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar"(depending upon on how your usecase
   is) in the libraries folder or .m2 repository.
2. Or,it could also
   be the jar may not be added in your classpath(add an entry for this
   jar in your .classpath file), depending upon how your application is
   built.