# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hive

For connecting hive through spring application i have added below dependency in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
 <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
  <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.3</version>
    <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
  <artifactId>hive-service-rpc</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

> But still i am facing the below exception :: Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hive/service/cli/HiveSQLException at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:132) at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:113)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2836)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2832)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
>   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
>   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
>   ... 97 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
>   ... 116 more

---

Any one please tell me if any jars i am missing or what is the issue.Using  the same url i am able to connect through beeline

```
 $HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/TEST_DB
```

I have refer below url but it contains no answer

[org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/ipc/CallerContext$Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149032/org-apache-hive-service-cli-hivesqlexception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-or)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [hive-service.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-service). Add this and verify if it works.

Comment: i have already added this jar i.e hive-service 2.1.1 still this exception exist.

Comment: You're using Spring right? there are some Spring specific jars in that link, use them. `hive-service_2.1.1.jar` is not one of them. Look for the blue label that says Spring framework.

Comment: then do i need to use hive-service with different version or more specifically repository type should be spring-plugins ,is that you want to convey?

Comment: @SumeetTiwari that is my understanding, yes.

Comment: i have dependency of 1.2.1000.2.4.2.12-1 hive-service but it is not able to download the jars,this jar is present in maven central repository or noti.e error ] Failed to execute goal on project spring-hive: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.evolvus.hive:spring-hive:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.hive:hive-service:jar:1.2.1000.2.4.2.11-1 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Comment: Wait, can you post the driver class that you are using? Are you using `Class.forName(DRIVER)` in your code?

Comment: i am using org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver  driver class

Comment: What about `Class.forName`? try using that in your code. Your exception is here. `.(HiveConnection.java:132) at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect`. It'd help if you will post the code.

Comment: using normal jdbc program i am able to access i.e using class.forName(),but after that i have tried to use the same in existing application then got this exception .Lots of dependency is their in that application so decided to go create one simple spring program and connect with hive

Comment: please do visit below link with ref code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561831/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-hadoop-hive-service-hiveserverexcep

Comment: i have tried here but not  able to connect with hive

Comment: This question seem to be facing an issue with the driver class. The other question you mentioned is related to hive-service.jar is what I think.

Comment: if you help me to solve this problem then it may help me to solve this issue i.e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561831/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-hadoop-hive-service-hiveserverexcep

Answer (score 1):

finally able to connect hive through spring application.This type of exception which i have asked we got due to compatibility issue with jars i.e some version are not compatible to used with spring.Below i am attaching my pom.xml for more clarification.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>spring-hadoop-samples-hive</artifactId>

    <name>Spring Hadoop Samples - Hive</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hadoop-samples</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.hadoop.version>2.3.0.M1</spring.hadoop.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.7.1</hadoop.version>
        <hive.version>1.2.1</hive.version>
        <!-- <hive.version>2.1.1</hive.version> -->
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.hadoop.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- runtime Hive deps start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-shims</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- runtime Hive deps end -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                    <configurationSourceDirectory>src/main/config</configurationSourceDirectory>
                    <copyConfigurationDirectory>true</copyConfigurationDirectory>
                    <!-- Extra JVM arguments that will be included in the bin scripts -->
                    <extraJvmArguments>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Dhive.version=${hive.version}</extraJvmArguments>
                    <programs>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>org.springframework.samples.hadoop.hive.HiveApp</mainClass>
                            <name>hiveApp</name>
                        </program>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>org.springframework.samples.hadoop.hive.HiveClientApp</mainClass>
                            <name>hiveClientApp</name>
                        </program>
                        <program>
                            <mainClass>org.springframework.samples.hadoop.hive.HiveAppWithApacheLogs</mainClass>
                            <name>hiveAppWithApacheLogs</name>
                        </program>
                    </programs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>assemble</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>config</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <copy todir="target/appassembler/data">
                                    <fileset dir="data"/>
                                </copy>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After that you may encounter with authentication issue while running the appliation.Please run below command for that.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp
hadoop fs -chmod a+w /tmp
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse
hadoop fs -chmod a+w /user/hive/warehouse
```

If their is no folder structure then it will create and give the read,write permission to that.