# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$ThriftHiveProcessorFactory

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, github, hive

hi everyone i have refer below link to create one sample of spring with hive integration.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/tree/master/hadoop/hive

When i used as it is only spring version i have changed,below is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.hadoop.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring.hadoop.version>
        <spring.integration.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
        <!-- <spring.integration.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>  -->    
        <hadoop.version>1.0.1</hadoop.version>
        <hive.version>0.8.1</hive.version>
        <thrift.version>0.7.0</thrift.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.6</logback.version>
        <querydsl.version>2.9.0</querydsl.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.hadoop.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>                
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>      
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>           
        </dependency>   

        <!-- thrift only needed as compile time to support 'native' implementation of HivePasswordRepository -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
            <version>${thrift.version}</version>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
            <version>${thrift.version}</version>
        </dependency>               

        <!-- runtime Hive deps start -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-builtins</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-shims</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>               
        </dependency>               

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- runtime Hive deps end -->      

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>                   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

in this case i got below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hiveServer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10000.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158)
    at com.evolvus.nxtgen.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:15)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10000.
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:93)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:75)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.hive.HiveServerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(HiveServerFactoryBean.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 13 more
```

After refer to some Q & A here i changed my pom.xml to this as below to overcome this issue.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.hadoop.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring.hadoop.version>
        <!-- <spring.integration.version>2.1.3.RELEASE</spring.integration.version> -->
        <spring.integration.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>      
        <hadoop.version>1.0.1</hadoop.version>
        <!-- <hive.version>0.8.1</hive.version> -->
        <hive.version>2.1.1</hive.version> 
        <!-- <thrift.version>0.7.0</thrift.version> -->
        <thrift.version>0.9.3</thrift.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.6</logback.version>
        <querydsl.version>2.9.0</querydsl.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.hadoop.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>                
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <!-- <version>1.2.1000.2.4.2.12-1</version>      -->    
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>           
        </dependency>


        <!-- thrift only needed as compile time to support 'native' implementation of HivePasswordRepository -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
            <version>${thrift.version}</version>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
            <artifactId>libfb303</artifactId>
            <version>${thrift.version}</version>
        </dependency>               

        <!-- runtime Hive deps start -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-builtins</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${hive.version}</version> -->
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-shims</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>           

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>               
        </dependency>               

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- runtime Hive deps end -->      

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>                   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

in this case got below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/service/HiveServer$ThriftHiveProcessorFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:159)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:255)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158)
    at com.evolvus.nxtgen.HiveApp.main(HiveApp.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$ThriftHiveProcessorFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

I already tried by changing the port no from 10000 to 10001.Still facing the issue.Please any one know this.Thanks for giving yours valuable time.I am using java 1.8 and Hadoop 2.7.3 , Hive 2.1.1.For your information i have created a new project as it is in the github link(didn't import the same project to the workspace)

Comment: I have answer this please refer below url [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547186/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-hive-service-cli-hivesqlexception/44896798#44896798](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547186/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-hive-service-cli-hivesqlexception/44896798#44896798)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred to me when it can't find `hive-service-*.jar` in hadoop classpath.

Just copy the `hive-service-*.jar` to your hadoop lib folder or export classpath in hadoop-env.sh. I have mentioned how to add classpath below.

Add this line in hadoop-env.sh:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-*.jar
```

Change the path of the jars to point to hive installation folder.